# PostgresQL windows installer - blank screen-

Tags: postgresql, windows-installer, windows-vista, postgresql-9.2

Been trying to install Postgres version 9.2.4-1 on my desktop (Vista x32). Downloaded the installer but upon running the .exe a blank window came up with the installer name as title.

This was strange as the installer worked fine on my office pc, also running vista x32. I've tried googling but there are no solutions abound. I've tried the following steps:-

1. redownloaded the installer. no dice.
2. downloaded older versions of the installer and the x64 version (same problem)
3. fully updated vista.
4. ensured admin rights
5. tried running from command line.
6. disabled UAC and windows firewall.
7. event logs did not show anything nor was there an install-postgresql.log in the %temp%    folder.
8. Disabled antivirus
9. Followed the FAQ on common installation errors.

my user variable PATH:

C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;C:\Program              Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib

been going crazy trying to figure this out! please help.

Comment: Please see http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_Installation and http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Running_%26_Installing_PostgreSQL_On_Native_Windows#Common_installation_errors . Got antivirus software installed? Disable it.

Comment: Tried every single (commonly encountered) scenario listed in the wiki. No dice so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

> right click on .exe
>   run as administrator

Apparently running the installer on an administrator account wasn't enough. Which was odd as I could just run the installer on my office pc without jumping through this additional hoop. Can't believe I just spent hours on this non-issue!

Thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 0):

As the installation is hung\incomplete in your case install log names should be bitrock_installer.log or bitrock_installer_xxx.log, where xxx is a number (the process ID of the installation attempt). Please check the %temp% dir for this file. This will log all manner of data about the installation, and is invaluable when troubleshooting. The log will be called install-postgresql.log if the installation completed successfully. If not, the installer may not have been able to rename it, in which case the name will be either bitrock_installer.log or bitrock_installer_xxx.log, where xxx is a number.

Comment: Couldn't find the bitrock_installer.log in the temp folder. To double check I've deleted everything i could from the temp folder and reran the installer. It created 5 .TMP files which were destroyed upon exiting the blank installer window but no .log files were generated.